# what's the best solution to make kotlin and elasticsearch comunicate

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, elasticsearch

Using google i found two possible solution for now:

-using spring boot with kotlin

-using this kotlin client https://github.com/jillesvangurp/kt-search

I've already finished the android client application in kotlin but now i have to find a way to make this client comunicate with elasticsearch.
What would it be the best solution for my problem that i could look up online

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First, if you don't use Spring in the current application, integrating it (if possible) would be a lot of work and most likely not worth it.

Another alternative would be to use the officially supported Java client for Elasticsearch (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/index.html).

BUT, you should keep in mind that, if you put the Elasticsearch client in your client application, that the credentials, you may use, will also be in the client application.
They could be accessible for everyone using the Android client and the user could perform any request on the Elasticsearch. Also you couldn't change them without updating the client.
So, it is likely better to use a Three-Tier-Architecture (https://www.ibm.com/topics/three-tier-architecture) and creating an API service to handle the Elasticsearch requests.